# DB Connection failure from App server

Tags: sql-server, networking, database-connection

I have installed Microsoft SQL server on my windows VM. And trying to access that DB server from RHEL App server. Ping is working fine but when in try to install application, it is giving DB connection failure error. Could someone help on trouble shooting this?

Thank you

Comment: Further to above, even after RDP to windows VM and try to connect to SQL DB with IP address, it is not getting connected. However, it is connecting with domain name (like sql-server-1) using MS SQL mgmt studio

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the error you are getting? (error code, message etc,)